# Is it possible to paint a texture over another texture when they both have different displacement maps in Cycles?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, texture-painting

I've always wanted to create a scene where I could have a grass texture with planes as grass and then a dirt texture side by side with their own separate bump maps and displacement maps. If not what would be the best way to achieve something similar to this. 
Thanks